# Where can I find a horror adventure/campaign writing guide?

Tags: books, ravenloft, horror

I seem to remember an old (ebook format?) book I read, with instructions on how to write a quality adventure based in the Ravenloft universe. The book was distinguished by writing in a general style, it was trying to teach about writing and about properly scaring your group, as opposed to teaching the standard rules and instructions that tend to come with RPG manuals.

Does anyone know what the title of this book is, and where I might find a copy?

Comment: How old is old? Ravenloft was first published in 1983. Do you remember roughly how long ago it was that you read it? There was a Ravenloft Dungeon Master's Guide for D20 published by White Wolf, which is still available as a PDF:

Comment: http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product_info.php?products_id=2480&it=1

ISBN: 1-58846-084-3

Comment: The book that you are talking about sounds a lot like "Nightmares of Mine" by Ken Hite, although that isn't a Ravenloft book at all.

ISBN: 1-55806-367-6

Comment: @Azeari that's the one! Wow, my memory does *not* remember things properly

Comment: I had a feeling it might be. There's really no other book like it (except perhaps for GURPS Horror 3ed, which was also written by Ken Hite...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The book that you describe sounds a lot like "[Nightmares of Mine](http://shop.mjolnirgames.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=128_30_34&products_id=248)" by [Ken Hite](http://www.indiepressrevolution.com/outofthebox/) (published by Iron Crown in 1999; [ISBN: 1-55806-367-6](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=K4z6PAAACAAJ)), although that isn't specific to Ravenloft or indeed any RPG or genre.

> This book explores the ins and outs of what makes a great horror story and what it takes to make a great horror story into one of the most memorable role playing experiences you and your players will ever participate in. Inside, you will find:
>
> - Definitions of the concepts and types of horror that can be used to tell a story
> - Definitions of how horror can work in any type of campaign: fantasy, historical, modern, or sci-fi
> - Guidelines showing how to incorporate horror into different styles of games

It's definitely one that's on my regular reading list for awesome GM advice books. There's really no other book like it (except perhaps for [GURPS Horror 3rd ed](http://www.sjgames.com/gurps/books/horror/), which was also written by Ken Hite...)

Comment: That's a good one, I learned a lot from it when running my own horror games.

Comment: GURPS Mysteries is a good companion to GURPS Horror if you want to do investigation/horror.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I have no idea which book you mean, but you may want to check out the following two archives of *Ravenloft* netbooks, if you haven't visited them yet - you might find the pdf you're looking for:

[The Fraternity of Shadows: Ye Olde Library](http://www.fraternityofshadows.com/Library.html)

[Secrets of the Kargatane](http://www.kargatane.com/)

Also, running a search for "Ravenloft" on [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com) might help.

Comment: Sadly, the book I am looking for doesn't seem to be on any of the tree locations you've mentioned. :(

Comment: The silver lining of this is that by this we've narrowed down the possible answers quite a bit. :)